Energy to produce particles in different frames
I am a fourth year undergraduate student taking a course in Nuclear and Particle physics.
When asked nuclear related questions like "how much energy is produced [in the LAB frame] in the decay $X \to Y+Z,$ we can easily work this out. Suppose $X$ is at rest in the lab frame, then the energy produced is $E = (m(X) - m(Y)-m(Z))c^2$.
In particle physics, when we are finding the energy required to make new particles, we seem to take a different approach- one that leads to wildly different answers to the above method, but I expect is more correct. The concern I have is that it feels like it is possible to construct a situation where the reactants have sufficient energy in one frame to produce a particle, but not sufficient energy in another frame to produce that particle. For example, suppose we were going to smash a $\bar{\nu}_e$ into an $e^-$ at rest, and we wanted to find the heaviest particle we could possibly produce with a fixed incident energy $E_{\bar{\nu}_e}$ in the LAB frame. The 'nuclear' way would say this energy was given by: $$m(\bar{\nu}_e)c^2 + E_{\bar{\nu}_e},$$ and the 'particle' way would say this energy was given by: $$\sqrt{s} = \sqrt{(\tilde{p}_{e^-}+\tilde{p}_{\bar{\nu}_e})^2}=\sqrt{m(e^-)^2c^4 + m(\bar{\nu}_e)^2c^4+2m(e^-)c^2E_{\bar{\nu}_e}}$$ (tildes denote four vectors).
These two expressions give wildly different answers, the 'particle' way leading to much lower energies (you require much more energetic particles to produce the same mass particle). Somehow this is related to my point above, that the reactants need to have sufficient energy to make new particles in all frames, but I'm not seeing how this fits together yet. Maybe someone has some insight.

I do not understand the ans in lab frame, but when you do four momentum conservation, both should give the same
